# Is there a way to increase the 'Foreign Address' Field in 'netstat -tup'

Tags: netstat

OK, my question is completely in the title.

Is there a way to increase the 'Foreign Address' Field in 'netstat -tup' ?

*(for those who never used -tup, it is the same like -tupn but resolving the hostname of the IPs)*

Although netstat was released in 1983, the same year like the Domain Name System was introduced on the arpanet, it seems like up to me nobody felt the stringent necessity to increase the 'Foreign Address' Field.

For me it is more or less useless because URLs are seldom shorter then 15 chr.

So I decided to ask you this question. Maybe someone has an idea.

**Q&A Section**

*Question:* What is the output of netstat--version
*Answer:*

```
net-tools 1.60
netstat 1.42 (2001-04-15)
Fred Baumgarten, Alan Cox, Bernd Eckenfels, Phil Blundell, Tuan Hoang and others
+NEW_ADDRT +RTF_IRTT +RTF_REJECT +FW_MASQUERADE +I18N
AF: (inet) +UNIX +INET +INET6 +IPX +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +ATALK +ECONET +ROSE
HW:  +ETHER +ARC +SLIP +PPP +TUNNEL -TR +AX25 +NETROM +X25 +FR +ROSE +ASH +SIT +FDDI +HIPPI +HDLC/LAPB +EUI64
```

Comment: Are you talking about the netstat in the [net-tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-tools/) package? If so, give it the `-W` (wide) option.

Comment: Hallo @MarkPlotnick The -W option does not enlarge the "Foreign Address" field, it is still 15 + 1 + 5 chr long, but overwrites the next column called "State".

Comment: Can you tell us the output of `netstat --version` or `netstat -V` ?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I edited the question and wrote the output in it.